# Setting a delegate for UITableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this for my table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CurrentItemsCell {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let responseItems = currentItemsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(currentItem: responseItems)

        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell
    } else {
        return CurrentItemsCell()
    }

}
```

Here is my cell stuff.

```
class CurrentItemsCell: UITableViewCell {
    ...
    weak var mDelegate:MyProtocolImage?
    ...
}

@IBAction func showImages(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
    mDelegate?.sendIndexPathBack(row: indexPath.row)
    print("FROM THE CELL CLASS")
}

protocol MyProtocolImage: class {
    func sendIndexPathBack(row: Int)
}
```

Inside of the UITableView I tried to add cell.mDelagate = self but there is an error.

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ItemResultsViewController' to type 'MyProtocolImage?'
```

Which now if I do `cell.mDelegate = self as! MyProtocolImage`, the syntax is fine, but the app crashes.

Basically, I have a button inside of each cell, I need to get the indexRow of the cell, so I can get the itemId of whatever item's button was pressed. I then have to send the itemId to a new ViewController (a modal) with a Seque.

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the `as! MyProtocolImage`. Instead, declare that your class conforms to the protocol.

```
class ItemResultsViewController: UITableViewController, MyProtocolImage {
```

Then add the implementation of the delegate method to your `ItemResultsViewController` class:

```
func sendIndexPathBack(row: Int) {
    // do something useful
}
```

Now you can do:

```
cell.mDelagate = self
```

BTW - you should not have an `indexPath` property in your cell class. That can use further issues. And your delegate should pass itself as a parameter to the delegate method. Let the implementer of the delegate method determine the cell's index path as needed. A cell should never be told its index path because it can be wrong over time.

Update your cell and protocol:

```
@IBAction func showImages(_ sender: Any) {
    mDelegate?.sendIndexPathBack(cell: self)
    print("FROM THE CELL CLASS")
}

protocol MyProtocolImage: class {
    func sendIndexPathBack(cell: CurrentItemsCell)
}
```

Then in the implementation of the delegate method:

```
func sendIndexPathBack(cell: CurrentItemsCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        // do something useful
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to consider your naming conventions. `MyProtocolImage` should probably be `CurrentItemsCellDelegate`. And `sendIndexPathBack` should reflect what action is really taking place such as `currentItemsCellShowImages(for cell: CurrentItemsCell`)`.

Comment: Yea I usually work on these things as proof of concepts, and then when I know I have it all working right, ill go back and refractor. Thanks so much!